# error after publishing website and deploying it..

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i did an application and published it and deployed it to online server. When I run that link it is throwing an error that login master page does not exist & I replaced ~ to  in design page now it throwing an error

> Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_login.master.cdcab7d2'. Make sure
>   that it is compiled before accessing the page.

```
Line 1:  <%@ master language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Login, App_Web_login.master.cdcab7d2" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ucMainFooter.ascx" TagName="ucMainFooter" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
Line 3:
```

Comment: i cleaned my temp files and tried all possibilities but still cant overcome this problem

Comment: are you using Visual Studio publish ? if yes it may be same prob i once had, try changing configuration to debug, publish it, change back to release and then publish it again, use the files in the published folder to move onto your online server

Comment: Have you checked 'Allow this precompiled site to be updatable' when publishing? I have got errors like this when publishing when that's checked.

Comment: yes i checked allow this precompiled site to be updatable